# How to find duplicate files in an AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, duplicates

Is there a way to recursively find duplicate files in an Amazon S3 bucket? In a normal file system, I would simply use:

```
fdupes -r /my/directory
```

Answer (score 18):

There is no "find duplicates" command in Amazon S3.

However, you do do the following:

- Retrieve a **list of objects** in the bucket
- Look for objects that have **the same** `ETag` (checksum) and `Size`

They would (extremely likely) be duplicate objects.

Comment: What method would you recommend to check for the same `ETag` and `Size`?

Comment: When you retrieve a list of objects using the [`list-objects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html) command, it includes the `ETag`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a git repository: https://github.com/chilts/node-awssum-scripts which has a js script file to find out the duplicates in a S3 bucket. I know, pointing you to an external source is **not** recommended, but I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto3
s3client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=region)
etag = s3client.head_object(Bucket='myBucket',Key='index.html')['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['etag']
print(etag)
```

Comment: Please add some explanations to your answer

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled upon it and wanted to elaborate on John Rotenstein's answer with code:

```
import boto3
import hashlib

def find_duplicate_files(bucket_name):
  # Create an S3 client
  s3 = boto3.client('s3')

  # Retrieve a list of objects from the bucket
  objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)

  # Create a dictionary to store the checksums
  checksums = {}

  # Iterate through the objects
  for obj in objects['Contents']:

    # Download the object and compute its checksum
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=obj['Key'])

    data = response['Body'].read()
    checksum = hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()

    # Add the checksum to the dictionary
    if checksum in checksums
      # If the checksum already exists in the dictionary, it's a duplicate
      print(f'Duplicate file: {obj["Key"]}')
    else:
      checksums[checksum] = obj['Key']
  print('Done')
```

One challenge this option presents, however is it only compares absolutely identical files. It doesn't take into account `similar` files, and it can't.

There is a free non-AWS alternative that can find similar files based on their contents however:

```
from mixpeek import Mixpeek

mixpeek = Mixpeek("API_KEY")
# get a list of files

candidates = mixpeek.list("file_ids")

# find similar files
similar_files = mixpeek.tooling(candidates, find_similar=True)
```

[Full tutorial here](https://mixpeek.com/learn/find-duplicates)