# S3 avoid loading of duplicate files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following work flow.
I need to identify duplicate files on S3 in order to avoid duplicates on my destination ( Redshift ).

- Load files to S3 every 4 hours from FTP Server ( File storage structure : year/month/date/hour/minute/filename)
- Load S3 to Redshift once all of the files are pulled ( for that interval )

This is a continuous job that will be running every 4 hour.

**Problem :**

Some times the files with same content but different file names are present on S3. These files can belong to different intervals or different days. For example if a files arrives say one.csv on 1st Oct 2018 and contains 1,2.3,4 as a content then it is possible that on 10th Oct 2018 a file may arrive with same content 1,2,3,4 but with different file name.
I want to avoid to load this file to S3 if the contents are same.
I know that I can use file hash to identify the two identical files, But my problem is how to achieve this on S3 and that too with so much of files.
What will be the best approach to proceed ?

Bascially, I want to avoid loading of data to S3 that is already present.

Comment: I guess an ETag & size comparison would be the fastest. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37064007. Also read on how to ensure ETag calculation is consistent (i.e. what properties of the upload operation you must maintain the same): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html

Comment: Maybe use Lambda that's triggered on files dropped into S3. Retrieve the etag (or otherwise calculate a hash for the file), then look that up in a DynamoDB 'already-seen' table. If not there, then store the etag/hash in DynamoDB. If there, then delete or otherwise move the S3 file so that it's not loaded to Redshift. The reason I propose persisting the etags/hashes to DynamoDB is that lookup will be much faster than listing all S3 objects and retrieving their etags to do the duplicate lookup.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another table in redshift ( or anywhere else actually like MySQL or dynamodb ) which will contain Etag/md5 hash of files uploaded.

You might already be having a script which is running every 4 hours and is loading data into redshift. In this same script, after data is loaded successfully into redshift; just make an entry into this table. Also, put a check in this same script(from this new table) before loading data into Redshift.

You need to make sure, that you load this new table with all the Etags of files you have already loaded into redshift.